# Sacar el ID siguiente SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy trantando de hacer una consulta en MySQL

Dados los siguiente datos:

```
SELECT num_empleado, ID
FROM [WORKDAY_TRANSACTIONS]
where tipo_transaccion='EXCEDENCIA'
```

Necesito saber el **ID siguiente de transacción (Después del ID de excedencia) que tiene cada usuario con el tipo_transacción=REINCORPORACIÓN**

Tiene que ser justo el de después, ya que un mismo usuario puede tener muchas transacciones de reincorporación.

¿Me podéis ayudar?

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Bienvenido PeepMol a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon la estructura de tus tablas y un ejemplo real para q se te pueda entender

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.